# Angular 4: error this.authenticationservice.login(...) is null in LoginComponent

Tags: angular

I am updating my question here. Basically, I want to log in to a system. It works but the service does not return a correct Observable type to the LoginComponent. I am using httpclient for interceptor purposes. Now I can read the the success and failure of my login attempts (custom message from the server, with http status) but I am failing to return the correct response to the login component, hence the error.

When i click the login button, token is generated or a proper message is returned from the server. But I keep on getting the error in my console (and hence, cant redirect to dashboard):

**this.authenticationservice.login(...) is null**

I tried return string or number (the server codes or message) but another error follows up. If it helps, I am following a tutorial from [here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular-2305b8fd654b) but the author don't reply to questions.

**login.component.ts:**

```
addPost(post) {

   this.authenticationservice.login(post).subscribe(
      res => {

      console.log(res);

        if(res['status']== 200)
          {
             this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
          }else{
            this.loginError = true
            this.loginAlert = res.message;
            console.log('here');
          }
      },
       err => {
        return err;

      }
```

**My service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  private url: string = environment.apiURL + 'start/login/';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  login(post): Observable<any> {

  let send_data ={
  username: post['username'],
  password:post['password'],
  client_id:environment.client_id,
  client_secret:environment.client_secret,
  grant_type:environment.grant_type
  };

 interface LoginResponse {
  access_token: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_time: string;
  token_type: string;
  expire_on:string;
  lang:string;
  groups:string[];
};

let reply = {
    message:'',
    status:400
}


 this.http.post<LoginResponse>(environment.apiURL + 'start/login/', send_data,{ observe: 'response' }).subscribe(
      data => {
        //console.log("User Login: " + data.access_token);
        console.log(data);
        reply['status']=200;

        return data;

      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {



        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log("Client-side error occured.");

        } else {
         console.log(err.error['detail']);
          console.log("Server-side error occured.");


        }
      }
    );



    return null;



  }


  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I wanted to send token on every request, but it failed

You have to use HTTP Interceptors to achieve this. You can follow [this](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) tutorial.

> However, it doesn't capture error from the back end which replies with status 200 or 400 (so far only 200 is caught)

This is because

> I prefer to send a string (an error from the back-end) to my login component.

If you send the proper error response from server then it'll catch it. Angular doesn't know whether the string is a success or error. But if are adamant about string response then you can check error code manually.

Using proper error response is strongly advised.

Comment: For e.g. if log in was sucess, ti replies http status 200. Else, it replies with 400 and a 'detail' of what went wrong (there are two cases in my app). Now I am only capturing or seeing res.status==200. Else statement dont work tho i am sure I am forgetting something. Thanks anywya